# running pep8 or pylint on cython code

Tags: cython, pylint, pep8, flake8

Is there any way to use pep8 with cython files?

pep8 does not work with operators for example.

```
getline(& line)
```

produces error:

```
E225 missing whitespace around operator
```

Now if i try to fix it and run this:

```
getline( & line)
```

produces error:

```
 E201 whitespace after '('
```

Comment: `pep8` is a code checker for `python` code. `cython` is a different language. I don't think this is possible.

Comment: It really only fails on operators

Comment: Well, you can write weird c stuff in cython. I am pretty sure that operators are not the only problem.

Comment: its the only errors I am seeing.  Most people write a pxd or .h files and extern from there

Comment: the only way I see would be to write python compatible code, using decorators and other functions (eg `reference` or similar) provided by cython.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?

Comment: no, I haven't heard from anyone on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [cython-lint](https://github.com/MarcoGorelli/cython-lint)

### Installation

```
$ pip install cython-lint
```

### Usage as a pre-commit hook

See [pre-commit](https://github.com/pre-commit/pre-commit) for instructions

Sample `.pre-commit-config.yaml`:

```yaml
-   repo: https://github.com/MarcoGorelli/cython-lint
    rev: v0.10.1  # put most recent version here
    hooks:
    -   id: cython-lint
    -   id: double-quote-cython-strings
```

### Command-line example

```
$ cython-lint my_file_1.pyx my_file_2.pyx
my_file_1.pyx:54:5: 'get_conversion_factor' imported but unused
my_file_2.pyx:1112:38: 'mod' defined but unused
my_file_3.pyx:4:9: dangerous default value!
my_file_3.pyx:5:9: comma after base type in definition
```

Answer (score 5):

The neural network library [Chainer](https://github.com/pfnet/chainer) has a pretty handy flake8 [config](https://github.com/pfnet/chainer/blob/master/.flake8.cython) for Cython:

```
[flake8]
filename = *.pyx,*.px*
exclude = .eggs,*.egg,build
ignore = E901,E225,E226,E227
```